# POST call using jquery AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to build an ASP.NET MVC web service in which I am trying to make a POST call in javascript using jQuery ajax as below.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/bug/CreateBug",
      type: "POST",
      data: rowData,
      contentType: "application/json",
      datatype: "json", //return type
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (xhr) {
          alert('error');
      }
  });
```

I keep getting the error `TypeError: e is undefined`. I tried adding a log statement just before this ajax call and things are working fine. Not sure what am I missing out on. My `rowData` looks something like below.

```
{
    "Date": "2016-12-31",
    "Id": "1234-csj4-sadf-random",
    "Scenario": "abc",
    "IsFixed": "No"
}
```

My C# code in the controller looks something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateBug(string jsonRequest)
{
    var bugId = GetBugId(jsonRequest);

    return this.Json(bugId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I tried to test the above POST call using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and I got `jsonRequest` as `null`. Could someone pls help me out here on how can I get the POST request to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `data:Json.stringify(rowData)`

Comment: can you try JSON.stringify(rowdata)

Comment: posted updated code plz let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  try it hope it works
  $.ajax({
  url: "/bug/CreateBug",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(rowdata),
  contentType: "application/json",
  datatype: "json", //return type
  success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
  },
  error: function (xhr) {
      alert('error');
  }
  });
```

------ on controller 
  do something like this or the best approach is to create model with all these property and MVC will bind it for you.

```
    [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult CreateBug(string Id, string Date, string IsFixed ,   string Scenario)
 {
    var bugId = GetBugId(jsonRequest);

   return this.Json(bugId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Yeah it is now making the call to the MVC controller, but I am still getting `jsonRequest` as `null` in the controller.

Comment: @SohamC updated answer please take a look if u still have issue let me know .